# Columns to rows and count for summarizing in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have the following df in `pyspark`:

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| on | true | true |
| off | false | true |
| on | true | false |
| off | false | true |
| on | true | false |
| off | false | true |

and I would like to summarize it as shown below:

| col | id | true | false |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| col1 | on | 3 | 0 |
|  | off | 0 | 3 |
| col2 | on | 1 | 2 |
|  | off | 3 | 0 |

where the  integers represent the `count()` of `true` and `false` instances. I've tried using `unpivot` unsuccessfully.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You also can pivot your table (several times, so you can also use for comprehensive as well)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

c1 = df.groupBy('id').pivot('c1').count().withColumn('col', F.lit('c1'))
c2 = df.groupBy('id').pivot('c2').count().withColumn('col', F.lit('c2'))

c1.union(c2).fillna(0).show()

+---+---+----+-----+
|col| id|true|false|
+---+---+----+-----+
| c1| on|   3|    0|
| c1|off|   0|    3|
| c2| on|   1|    2|
| c2|off|   3|    0|
+---+---+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Few mechanics. List comprehension could be of help

#Pivot, in this case, iterate the df and pivot. That will give a list of dfs

```
cols=df.drop('id').columns
lst = [df.crosstab('id',c).withColumn('col', lit(c)) for c in cols]
```

#Use unionall or unionByName to reduce the list of dfs into one df. To do this, iterate each df in the lit renaming first column

```
df1 = reduce(DataFrame.unionByName, [y.withColumnRenamed(y.columns[0],'id') for y in lst])
```

df1.show()

```
+---+-----+----+----+
| id|false|true| col|
+---+-----+----+----+
| on|    0|   3|col1|
|off|    3|   0|col1|
| on|    2|   1|col2|
|off|    0|   3|col2|
+---+-----+----+----+
```